# How do you call UpdateModel when you use a ViewModel class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In MVC3, it seems that the default way to show properties of a model in your view is like so:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
```

This works fine if your model matches your object exactly.  But if you define a custom ViewModel, for example like in the [NerdDinner tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm)

```
public class DinnerFormViewModel {

  // Properties
  public Dinner     Dinner    { get; private set; }
  public SelectList Countries { get; private set; }

  // Constructor
  public DinnerFormViewModel(Dinner dinner) {
    Dinner = dinner;
    Countries = new SelectList(PhoneValidator.AllCountries, dinner.Country);
  }
}
```

Then your DisplayFor code would look like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Dinner.Title)
```

Which means the names of the form items are `Dinner.Title` instead of just `Title`, so if you call `UpdateModel` in your Action code, MVC won't "see" the properties it needs to see to update your `Dinner` class.

Is there a standard way of dealing with ViewModels that I'm overlooking for this scenario in MVC3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the 'prefix' parameter for UpdateModel method

UpdateModel(model.Dinner, "Dinner");

and if you need to update a specified properties only - use something like this

UpdateModel(model.Dinner, "Dinner", new []{"Title"});